# Android menu option problems in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-menu

I am developing an application which has a navigation drawer with 9 fragments.

### Two of nine fragments have tabs(4) interface implemented. Each tab has its own menu option and each fragments (other than with tabs) have their own menu options.

**Now the issue is,**
When i access or switch a simple fragment(without tabs) from the navigation drawer then its menu options and working fine.

**BUT**
When switching from a tabbed fragment after accessing , its menu options now appear on every other fragment in the navigation menu.

**For example** 
I access and switch from fragment "A" ->everything goody including all menu options 
I access and switch from fragment "B" (with tabs) then all the other fragments have its menu options.

If I didn't explain my problem effectively then do ask me again in the comments. I have been stuck with this problem since a week. Maybe a small problem or something else but do need some help from the people here.

////update//

1. SetHasMenuOptions implemented in each fragment. All fragments working fine except the tabbed ones
2. The main problem is, after accessing tabbed fragments all the menu options of other fragments are replaced by the tabbed menu options. 
   3 posting a  question through my phone cant post code sample. 
   Actually first i had problems like this with every fragment but then i implemented sethasmenuoptions
   And menu.clear() in each fragment and every fragment seems to work
   Like it should except the tabbed ones

Hope this info helps

Thanks

Comment: you should post some code as well.

Comment: Have you used `setHasOptionsMenu` to `true` in each fragment? Have you implemented the Override methods for menus in each fragment?

Comment: Are you saying that data of previous fragment is visible on current fragment?

Comment: @SharinglsCaring If your problem is as commented by activesince93, then setBackgroundColor for each Layout of the Fragment to white i.e. #ffffff.

Comment: Please see updated question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use transaction.addToBackStack(null) while fragment transaction and in layout set background colour to the fragments .

Comment: Hmm.i see. Btw what do u mean by setbackgroundcolor to fragments ?

Comment: Still the issue persists.